# Phonegap/Cordova orientation change Android 4

Tags: android, cordova, screen-orientation

I have a problem changing the orientation of the device (Android 4). In other versions it works fine.
Versión of Cordova: cordova-1.8.0.js / cordova-1.8.1.js
In Android 4 the app crash or show: "A network error occurred. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)"
I searched a lot about this and no answer solves the problem.

In most cases users suggest adding:
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"

In other cases:
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue",60000);

That not work for me :(

My manifest activity:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".AppNameActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The application should run on Android 2.2 to 4.

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I am having the exact same problem. It worked for me on phonegap 1.3.0, but the upgrade to cordova 1.8.1 or 1.9.0 created the same problem. The only solution I have found is to avoid the change of orientation, by adding screenOrientation as follows

```
    <activity
        android:name=".AppNameActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_app"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```